# LEFT OUTER JOIN get max() and include NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've managed to get the data out and include NULL values by using left outer join. This is my current query:

```
select s.user, a.id, a.datetime as date, a.total_time 
from steam_accounts s 
left outer join activity a on a.steam_id = s.id 
where s.user_id = 1
```

This returns this:

[image]

Which is almost perfect. But now I need to filter the results with `max(a.id)` and include null values if there are no matches from the outer join.

Here's what I've tried:

```
select s.id, s.user, max(a.id), a.datetime as date, a.total_time
from steam_accounts s
left outer join activity a on a.steam_id = s.id
where s.user_id = "1"
```

Result:

[image]

All the null values disappeared. I only wanted to filter out the first two results from the previous query.

This is my desired result:

[image]

Any much is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, MySQL doesn't have `OUTER APPLY` or `LATERAL JOIN`, so it will be less efficient, than it could have been. It seems that something like this should produce what you want:

```
SELECT
    s.id
    ,s.user
    ,ActivityIDs.MaxActivityID
    ,activity.datetime as date
    ,activity.total_time
FROM
    steam_accounts s
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            a.steam_id
            ,max(a.id) AS MaxActivityID
        FROM activity a
        GROUP BY a.steam_id
    ) AS ActivityIDs
    ON ActivityIDs.steam_id = s.id
    LEFT JOIN activity ON
        activity.id = ActivityIDs.MaxActivityID
WHERE
    s.user_id = 1
```

For each `steam_account` we find one `activity` with max ID in the first `LEFT JOIN`. Then we fetch the rest of `activity` details using found ID in the second `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, in this case they are true `left joins` and they should be `left`, not `inner`. The `where` clause filters only `steam_accounts`, not `activity` table. You must have misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `max(coalesce(a.id, 0))`

Any aggregation done on results with null will always return null

Comment: I received just the single result with this query. Appreciate your responce

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of would be using `ROW_NUMBER()` with partitioning functionality as in SQL Server or PostgreSQL. There's an example how to do this in MySQL here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/.

What comes next, I'd partition your result set by user and sort it by `date` DESCENDING and then take records where `ROW_NUMBER` is equals to 1.

I've given similar answer here using SQL Server functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30952154/3680098

It should produce you result set as follows:

[image: Result set]

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation to calculate the maximum value.  Then join in that record using another `left join`:

```
select s.user, a.id, a.datetime as date, a.total_time 
from steam_accounts s left outer join
     activity a
     on a.steam_id = s.id left outer join
     (select a.steam_id, max(a.id) as maxid
      from activity a
      group by a.steam_id
     ) amax
     on amax.steam_id = a.steam_id and amax.maxid = a.id
where s.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: I received no results using your query. Thank you for taking the time to respond

Comment: Wouldn't this produce the same number of rows as original query in the question? I think that the order or `left joins` is important here. The first `join` returns all rows from `activity`, the second `join` can't remove those that are not needed. My answer is essentially the same, but `joins` are in different order

Comment: @VladimirBaranov . . . Without sample data, it is a bit hard to tell what the order of the joins should really be.  You seem to have gotten that correct.